# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]facing this MIME Type issue react using vite "version": "5.6.0",

i need a solution how can i fix this issue

facing this issue in production

using  c-panel as a server

Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.